# How to implement confirmation dialog for switchpreference in Android?

Tags: android, preferences

I have switchpreference, when user change value I should show confirmation dialog and change value only if user click positive button, if user clicks negative value should not be changed.

Comment: call your confirmation inside the onPreferenceChange

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Because code after show() is executing and if I click negative button, switchpreference should be changed programmatically  and after that onpreferencechange will be called

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Set `OnPreferenceChangeListener` of your preference and return `false` to suppress modification. Show a dialog and manually change your preference value from there.

```
val myPreference = preferenceScreen.findPreference<SwitchPreference>("my_pref_key")!!
myPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { _, _ ->
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)/* ... */.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                myPreference.isChecked = !myPreference.isChecked
        }.show()
        false // skip the default behavior 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use alert dialog for confirmation with positive and negative buttons.

change value in positive button and leave code (do nothing) in negative button

```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
                                        setTitle("title").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                        .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.message))
                                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                        {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//change value here
                                            }
                                        }) .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // do nothing
                                    }
                                }).show();
```

Comment: I tried it, but in negative click we should revert value, because is was changed when onpreferenchechange called. As a result, in on negative click we should reveret changes and onpreferencehcnage will be called